# How to load script after ajax load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

```
var currentTallest = 0,
 currentRowStart = 0,
 rowDivs = new Array(),
 $el,
 topPosition = 0;

$('.blocks').each(function() {

$el = $(this);
topPosition = $el.position().top;

if (currentRowStart != topPosition) {

 // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
 for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
   rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
 }

 // set the variables for the new row
 rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
 currentRowStart = topPosition;
 currentTallest = $el.height();
 rowDivs.push($el);

} else {

 // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
 rowDivs.push($el);
 currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);

}

// do the last row
for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
  rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
}

});​
```

Hi, I'm usign the code above to create equal height columns for bootstrap, and it works. But I'm also using an infinite scroll librarie to load more content, and after I scroll down the script doesn't load in the new columns, I know that it is because ajax is loading after the scripts load. I know  the .ajaxComplete() handle should make this work, but I haven´t find the proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I get the question right, but you might need to check `$.getScript()` function and use it when your ajax call is complete:

```
$.ajax({

    // rest of the code

    complete: function() {
         $.getScript("path/to/script.js", function() {
              alert('All done!');
         });
    }
})
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: nice, I never knew about .getScript exposure. I will have to try that.

Comment: What if the script that I want to load is in the same script file? I'm compiling all scripts files into one

Comment: In this case I guess you need to wrap code you want executed after complete callback into a function  and just call the function, when your ajax call completes. 

Maybe you should create a jsfiddle, so I will be able to see the whole code and help you.